# Migrate Netty Websocket to Jetty Websocket

Tags: java, websocket, jetty, netty

My application uses a custom binary protocol which is implemented with Netty. Recently I changed it to use Netty's websocket implementation. It works quite well.

My application also has a Jetty web server included and it offers websockets, too. Now I want to reduce the opened ports my server needs and handle all http traffic with one port.

I see three options:

- Use either Netty or Jetty to proxy the traffic which belongs to the other implementation.
- Reimplement the custom protocol on Jetty without the use of Netty's channels and piplines.
- Create a custom implementation of Netty's channels that sends and receives it's data not over a socket but the methods Jetty's WebSocketListener offers.

Since Netty provides such a good api for writing binary protocols and a proxy sounds like extra problems to me I tend using the third approach. It shouldn't be too difficult to implement even though I don't know how to do it, yet.

Any thoughts what would be the best option and how I should implement it?